# It appears that your application still contains the default signing identifier

Tags: flutter, xcode10.2

The flutter app was working completely fine. After few days when i tried to run in ios device it said like this "open xcode and try product -> run and try fixing it . After doing this and still showed me the same error".

Product -> run  ,
flutter clean , 
flutter packages get , 
open ios/Runner.xcworkspace ,
signing in General(target) ->select team

Answer (score 21):

If anyone had their app running before and faced this error, what worked for me was (note I am using a Macbook pro), was to open up the terminal first.

Then navigate to the project folder and typing in `open ios/Runner.xcworkspace`.
This command will open up your xcode. From there you can select you device on the top (emulator or physical ios device), and click on `run`.

Once it builds and runs successfully, it will fix the issue you are facing, now you can go to VS code or android studio and try `flutter run` and it should work.

Comment: the fix works, but I'm getting this issue every single day. anyone knows why, or how to stop it?

Comment: That's just by design, look at the answer by @w461 below me

Answer (score 3):

If you see this error when trying to run your app on your iPhone for the first time, it's because your xCode signing identifier contains a default one and needs updating.

Here's how to solved this issue:

1. In VsCode, right click the ios folder and click Xcode.
2. In XCode, click Runner , The top option on the left then 'Signing & Capabilities'
3. Click 'Automatically manage signing'
4. Select your Team, if you don't have one setup, click 'Add an account' and continue to the next step.
5. Select "Add your Apple ID"
6. Click Manage Certificates then click the '+' button located in the corner , then click 'Apple Development' to add a signing certificate.
7. Click Done. Signing Certificate should display 'Apple Development: yourAppleID..."
8. Select your connected iPhone from the build destination dropdown - see screenshot[image: screenshot]
9. Click the big play button to run the build in xCode
10. Trust your iPhone - Open your iPhone settings > General > Device Management or VPN & Device Management > Under Developer APP, select Apple Development : your appleID > Click Trust "Apple Development: "your apple id...."
11. Open vsCode and run `flutter clean && flutter run`.

Answer (score 2):

To Fellow up with Harsh, if you have no paid Apple Developer license, your certificate runs out after a week.

In my case, I needed again to trust my developer certificate on my iPhone, again. Before that, I also received your error. If you open up your app with Xcode, you will see the real error message.

Comment: Yes exactly, if you have a paid version you can replace your signing identifier with the one in your app developer license. As a workaround for development you can sign temporary one week certificates through the steps I included in my answer. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Building for iOS, but the linked and embedded framework 'App.framework' was built for iOS Simulator. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')

Answer (score 0):

You are encountering this error because *com.example* hasn't been registered as a Bundle ID on your developer account. I encountered this error while trying to use platform methods. I rectified the issue by creating a new Bundle ID on my Apple Developer Account - something like com.abc.appName. Here, abc is the name of my company. And then created a new project with this Bundle ID. Open up Xcode and under Runner -> Runner Target -> Signing and Capabilities add your Team name and make sure the *automatically manage signing* option is turned on

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I added the exclusion of arm64 in Xcode because my simulator was not running due to some dependency (google map?). When i deleted this arm64 exclusion for ios sdk (left it for simulator) inside xcode, runner, build settings, excluded architecture. The app could run again on physical device.

Answer (score -7):

The default signing identifier is **com.example**.

Sounds like you haven't changed it.

Comment: Maybe you could add a short description of where this identifier can be changed?